# Extract table data and put them into dictionary with azure form recognizer

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, dictionary, azure-form-recognizer

I have searched related to my question but none found.

Below is my tried working code:

```
import json
from azure.core.exceptions import ResourceNotFoundError
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import FormRecognizerClient, FormTrainingClient
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential

credentials = json.load(open("creds.json"))

API_KEY = credentials["API_KEY"]
ENDPOINT = credentials["ENDPOINT"]

url = "https://some_pdf_url_which_contains_tables.pdf" #or image url which contains 
                                                       #table

form_recognizer_client = FormRecognizerClient(ENDPOINT, AzureKeyCredential(API_KEY))
poller = form_recognizer_client.begin_recognize_content_from_url(url)
form_data = poller.result()

for page in form_data:
    for table in page.tables:
        for cell in table.cells:
            for item in cell.text:
                print(item)
                ## But I need table in dictionary format with header names in keys and 
                ## values in values.
```

I hope I get some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [python Azure form recognizer documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-ai-formrecognizer/azure.ai.formrecognizer.documenttable?view=azure-python-preview),
you can use the 'to_dict' method.

```
result_table = form_data.tables[0].to_dict()
```

And then you can loop in the dictionary.

I hope it helps you !